# Did cement mix damage my grass?

Tags: lawn, grass, lawn-repair

A couple of weeks ago we had some brick-pavings re-cemented around our driveway.  Now all of the grass on the lawn that runs alongside the bricks has gone very orange.  I assume it was where the cement/sand mix was brushed onto the grass to clear up after the work.

I read that [cement is high in alkaline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkali%E2%80%93silica_reaction).  Would that have been the cause, and can grass recover naturally or should I purchase some kind of *treatment*, as opposed to scarifying it out and re-seeding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you wait and see - the other risk with brushing a cement sand mix onto grass is the sand itself might be high in salts, particularly if it wasn't washed sand. If it is a salt problem, that will sit in the soil for a while, possibly some months depending on quantity, until there's been sufficient rain to flush it all away. Given the type of work you've had done though, its unlikely there's a large amount of salt in the soil; even so any attempt at reseeding won't work till the salt's disappeared, so wait and see for a while seems to be the best option. YOu might even find the grass recovers on its own eventually.

Comment: Just checking back.  "*Wait and see*" worked out great!  The grass is starting to slowly grow back now.  I'm going to scarify the dead stuff and reseed.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the caustic lime used in masonry is likely the culprit. Depending on how much was washed onto the grass, it could kill the grass, rather than just cause a temporary die-back. However over time it will react with CO2 in the air and turn into calcium carbonate, which is alkaline, but not caustic. A pH test will tell you if you need to make any adjustments. Depending on what kind of grass you have growing, you are looking for soil pH in the 5.0 - 7.0 range.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I've done this and the 'dead' areas show `pH7` to `pH7.5`, so perhaps slightly biased toward alkaline?  Do you think that's worth treating or leaving for the rain to wash through?

Comment: That pH isn't high enough to cause any serious problems - even if it were permanent. Test again in a couple of months. Depending on the area you need to cover and how much you want to spend/risk, you could hedge your bets by seeding and watering the area. Even if the grass survives, overseeding is a nice treat for a lawn. But here's a thought. It just occurred to me that they could have used muriatic acid to clean mortar off bricks - that would certainly cause the burning to the grass that you describe. It would be similar to products like Burnout that use citric acid to kill plants.